# How to pass two parameters (NSString) and receive text-plain using Rest-Kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit-0.20

I have one service REST/JSON. It looks like:

```
 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
 @Path("/login/{userName}/{password}")
 public synchronized String login(@PathParam("userName") String userName,
 @PathParam("password") String password);
```

How do I consume this using RestKit in IOS?

Comment: Post the code you've tried and what it's doing wrong.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#object-request), there is an example that would help you to do what you're asking to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious that in order to send canonical restkit requests you ought to have entities, mappings etc. [Documentation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#object-request) provides explicit answer of how to do it.

I can also suggest you using the easy way:

```
 [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient postPath:@"your URL string" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"WHOOO");

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //
    }];
```

`responseObject` is what you need.